# Magento 1.9 calling getQuote function causing nesting level of '100' reached

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to get the quote in a tax model class,but it start showing me the following error:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in E:\wamp\www\lastposmogo\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 292

I tried to increase `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200` but it doesn't work.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: When you changed it from 100 to 200, did the error message change to "Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached"?

Comment: Is this a site that is working properly on a web server and not working properly on your local? Can you do a check to make sure you have all your files? Also check to see if local.xml is malformed.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you run a method A from a method B that eventuelly leads A to run B again and an endless circle is triggered of A and B running each other over and over untill so many levels that Xdebug cannot follow anymore.

The problem can only be found by digging deeper (debugging) in the getQuote() method you're calling from the tax modal class.

Put a breakpoint at the beginning and continue past it. You'll hit the same breakpoint again, but this time you can see the stack trace what has lead you up to this point. The source will be there.